# SQL - Update multiple tables, the same column across one query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have a postgres database

There are 3 tables, I'm trying to make a sql `UPDATE` statement that updates an `active` column in each table.

Table1 has a field record that looks like this:

```
table1_id: 40b77068-4693-4593-8ea9-996501414101
table1_name: Digital Only
active: false
```

Table2

```
table2_id: [some randomId we don't care about]
table1_fk: 40b77068-4693-4593-8ea9-996501414101
active: false
```

Table3 is the same as table 2

```
table2_id: [some randomId we don't care about]
table1_fk: 40b77068-4693-4593-8ea9-996501414101
active: false
```

I need a query that looks for the name "Digital Only" and it's ID on `table1`. Update it's active `column`. Update corresponding `active` columns in the 2 other tables matching the original ID in table1

The tables have pretty long names so ideally I want to alias them:

So far I have something along the lines of this in pseudocode

```
UPDATE a.active, b.active, c.active
INNER JOIN
FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
SET a.active=true, b.active=true, c.active=true
WHERE a.active=true, b.active=true, c.active=true
```

Not sure how to do this. The table relationships look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. The idea is first update `table1`, and to use the `returning` clause to return the `table1_id`, that can be used to `update` the two other tables:

```
with 
    t1 as (
        update table1
        set active = true
        where table1_name = 'Digital Only'
        returning table1_id
    ),
    t2 as (
        update table2
        set active = true
        from t1
        where table1_fk = t1.table1_id
    )
update table3
set active = true
from t1
where table1_fk = t1.table1_id
```

Comment: hm im getting an error on the `update table3` line, says syntax error

Comment: @VincentTang: this seems to work fine. See this [demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=24a2af817f8f61b07df58bccdb1df4ec).

Comment: how would I run this as completely seperate queries?
e.g. 3 queries

Answer (score 1):

A single update statement can only update 1 table at a time, so there are three ways to do this:

1. have your application look up the information and then wrap 3 updates in a single transaction
2. use a stored procedure to implement the lookup/update logic (then your app only needs to make 1 call)
3. play some SQL tricks by wrapping 3 update statements into a common table expression. this is the most “clever” way to do it.

Comment: do you have examples of #1

Comment: @VincentTang 4. trigger/rule. But I would have voted for the second option.

Comment: hm but i need to put this into a migration file / git-track it though

Comment: technically you could wrap it in a DO script, which would be a variant of #2, and should be re-usable.